# External Config Files (configSource) Dropped From Memory (MVC, C#, ASP.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, configuration, web-config

We are having an intermittent issue where config files, or more specifically subset of values within that data are getting lost into the ether. Truth be told I am at a loss as to how to approach it because I am unsure if it's a code, config, machine or IIS issue. To give you an idea of what's happening....

**What we are doing**

We have a config file that contains "price" drop down values :

```
<searchForm>
<priceLowerBoundValues>
<priceLowerBoundValue>2500</priceLowerBoundValue>
<priceLowerBoundValue>5000</priceLowerBoundValue>
....
</priceLowerBoundValues>
....
</searchForm>
```

These are contained within a file named searchForm.config. In web.config they are referenced as an external file like so.

```
<searchForm configSource="Config\searchForm.config" />
```

We have a custom configuration handler that inherits from IConfigurationSectionHandler. The gist of being this code here that gets the values.

```
var priceLowerBoundValueXPath = "/searchForm/priceLowerBoundValues/priceLowerBoundValue/text()";
searchFormLookups.PriceLowerBoundValues = section.SelectNodes(priceLowerBoundValueXPath).Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value));
```

Then the ONLY place we reference it, is when building a select list for the viewmodel. It looks a little like this :

```
SearchFormConfiguration.PriceLowerBoundValues.ToSelectList((parameters.PriceLowerBound != null) ? parameters.PriceLowerBound.Value : 0)
```

There is no modifications done to the list ever, and using resharper "Find Usages" only brings up this single call. No other point in the program touches these values.

**The Issue**

What will happen intermittently is that the drop down boxes on our webpage suddenly have only one value (e.g. 2500 in the price box). Do note it is not completely empty, but usually most values are gone. We have had similar issues of external configs dropping (almost completely) and it causes null reference errors across the place. e.g. it's still looking for a config that's supposed to be there, but it has been wiped from the face of the earth.

Stopping the website, stopping the app pool, and then bringing everything up again fixes the issue. Which made me initially think it could be something with memory usage, and external configurations being the first thing it drops, but I'm really unsure at this point.

Another thing to note. We have an app pool restart in the early hours of the morning everyday.

Any help with this is much appreciated, even if it's just a nudge into the right direction. As I say, I can't find any info on where to start, be it IIS settings or code. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea of what might me wrong.
Line

```
x.PriceLowerBoundValues = section.SelectNodes(...).Cast<XmlNode>().Select(...);
```

Basically a lazy enumerator over the XmlNodeList.
From MSDN docs:

> The XmlNodeList object returned by this method will be valid while the
>   underlying document remains unchanged. If the underlying document
>   changes, unexpected results may be returned (no exception will be
>   thrown).

Is there any chance that `the underlying document changes`?
Will there still be problem if you put values to, say, array? Like `..Select().ToArray();`